# Reuse an Angular component

Tags: angular

I am trying to reuse an Angular component given the following tree structure

[image]

The component I require is called existing-savings which lives in transfer-guide. I would like to use existing-savings in retirement-contributions-information

How would I go about this?

Currently I get this error compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
*'app-existing-savings' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-existing-savings' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, you are realizing `existings-savings` is a common feature/component, in other words you need it in **more than one places**.
Whenever this situation happens, it means you should move your common feature into an upper level and make it a module on its own.

I suggest you create a new module called `existings-savings` where only a single component will live (this pattern is called SCAM for *Single Component Angular Module*) and place it within your `shared` folder I believe (or any folder that you put things that are shareable). Then, you will inject the `ExistingsSavingsModule` in your `RetirementContributionsInformationModule`, it will allows you to use `existings-savings` component.

**Also**, don't forget to export `existings-savings` component in `exports`array in your `ExistingsSavingsModule` like so :

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [ExistingsSavingsComponent],
    declarations: [ExistingsSavingsComponent]
})
export class ExistingsSavingsModule{}
```

Comment: In general, 'If 'app-existing-savings' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module', mean that you need to add, the component to app.module or sub module.  But in this particular situation, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can import the transfer guide module into the benefits module. By doing that you can re-use not only the mentioned component, but also the other component which lives in transfer guide module. I suggest creating smaller modules to make it lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

For reuseable components I always create a `shared` module where these components get added. Then you can import that module anywhere you want. If you have a lot of reuseable components you should think about to group them to multiple 'shared' modules, which you can import anywhere.